# Betting Odds Decision Tree (Classification) in R

Tags: r, tree, classification

I am creating a decision tree in R (RStudio) using historic betting odds found at http://www.football-data.co.uk/englandm.php. I am interested in finding out how representative bookmakers' odds are of actual match outcomes. I am using match data from 2000/2001 to the 2017/2018 season. This equates to 6,480 matches. I cleaned the individual files and merged them together. Seeing as there were a lot of missing values for the betting odds columns (some had more odds from different bookies than others), I have used averages for home, draw and away win odds.

To avoid confusion, the variable names are:

- FTR: Full-Time Result (this is my target class and has 3 possibilities: H, D or A)
- AHWO: Average Home Win Odds
- ADO: Average Draw Odds
- AAWO: Average Away Win Odds

Here is my decision tree.

[Decision Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLNen.png)

The problem I am having is that my prediction system is not predicting any draws. I have played around with the parameters by adding more predictors but to no avail.

There is also an issue where when I use just home and away goals as predictors, I only get an accuracy rating of 0.9988802 (on my test data). Shouldn't this be 100%?

[Prediction frequency table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4peJ.png)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjC5.png)

[Classification accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97TIz.png)

Comment: What are the possible values of your predictions? How many do you have in your trainign data in proportion?

Comment: Hi @Statto; welcome to Stack OverFlow! It is better: to post code instead of images and images instead of links! To put an image put `!` before the first`[` in your link!

Comment: The target class is FTR (Full-Time Result) and the possible outcome categories are 'H', 'D' and 'A'. There are 6,480 entries. 80% of the dataset has been assigned  as the training set and 20% validation. What's interesting is when I assign, say 97% as the training and 3% as the validation, the frequency table does show a few draws. Although it's only looking at 200 matches in doing so.